# Cannot centre images in div?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble centering these hidden images in there divs. I want the displayed image centred and the thumbnails underneath?

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/mj7ba/1/

```
.displayed-image img {
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
text-align: centre;
}

.thumbnails {
 position: absolute;
 top: 250px;
 text-align: centre;
}
```

Comment: `centre` should be `center` :)\

Comment: Actually it should be `centre` since it's English. Unfortunately we are forced to use American English

Comment: yes, i know it should be 'center', spell corrector did it without me noticing, however the problem still stands even with the correct spelling of center??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: The `text-align` property should be applied to a **block container** and then it will centre that container's **inline content**. You should never apply it to an image, since an image is usually an inline element and can **never** be a container.

Second: Absolutely positioning an element takes it out of normal flow, so it can't be aligned normally.

Third: Most computer languages use American English, not standard English. Centre is spelt `center`.

You need something more along the lines of:

```
.displayed-image {
    text-align: center;
}

.displayed-image img {
    height: 200px;

}
.thumbnails {
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbnails img {
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: thanks, however, i need the displayed images to be positioned absolutely so when they are shown on hover of their correlating thumbnails they appear in the same position?

Comment: Use `display` instead of `visibility` and that won't be the case.

Comment: Just toggle between `display: none` and `display: inline` instead of `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`.

Comment: $(".thumbnails").on("mouseover mouseout", 'img', function () {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.displayed-image > img').each(function(index, element) {
        var el = $(element),
            display = el.attr('alt') === alt ? 'inline' : 'hidden';
        el.css('display', display);
    });
});   ??????

Comment: "'inline' : 'hidden'"? I said not to use hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example.

Problem was with containers.

[Js fiddle](http://goo.gl/zA4I5A)

Answer (score -1):

left. It will work.

```
.displayed-image img {

    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    text-align: centre;
    margin-left:200px;
}
.thumbnails {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    text-align: centre;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

If you want any other help just let me know.

Comment: Are you sure it must be `centre`?

Comment: Thanks for this, although I cannot predict the width of the images that will be inserted, so the margin-left will always be changing.

Comment: You can't predict the width of the container either

Comment: hey for this just take measurement of images and then place images in between.

Comment: Forcing a fixed width design and rewriting the CSS every time the images change is a really awful approach to centring content.